# Issue with CSS not being applied during development with Next.js

Tags: tailwind-css, next.js13

this is school project

i think issue is not found node-modules/@radix-ui

start is bigreact/app/page.tsx    -> bigreact is project name

```
"use client";


import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import  Login  from "@/components/component/login";
import { Signup } from "@/components/component/signup";
// import Booklist from '@/pages/booklist';

// 임포트 중괄호 규칙 다름 북리스트는 중괄호 넣으면 오류남
export default function Home() {

...skip...
<Login setShowLogin={setShowLogin} setShowBooklist={setShowBooklist} />
...skip...
```

i call component Login
if success

`router.push('/mainpage');`

push bigreact/pages/mainpage

this is mainpage

```
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Avatar } from "@/components/ui/avatar";
import { CardHeader, CardContent, Card } from "@/components/ui/card";
import { Navibar } from '../components/component/navibar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import BookDetailComponent from '../components/component/bookdetailcomponent'; // 상세 정보 컴포넌트 임포트
import Forum from '../components/component/forum';
import Booklist from '../components/component/booklist';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default function Mainpage({ }) {
  const [selectedBookId, setSelectedBookId] = useState(null);
  const [SelecteCompoId, setSelecteCompoId] = useState<number | null>(0);
  const showBookDetails = (bookId) => {
    setSelectedBookId(bookId);
  };

  const renderContent = () => {
    switch (SelecteCompoId) {
      case 1:
        return <Booklist setSelecteCompoId={setSelecteCompoId} />;
      case 2:
        return <BookDetailComponent bookId={selectedBookId} setSelectedBookId={setSelectedBookId} setSelecteCompoId={setSelecteCompoId} />;
      case 3:
        return <Forum setSelecteCompoId={setSelecteCompoId} />;
      case 4:
        return <Booklist setSelecteCompoId={setSelecteCompoId} />;
      default:
        return <Booklist setSelecteCompoId={setSelecteCompoId} />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen min-w-full bg-[#FF4F6]">
      <Navibar setSelecteCompoId={setSelecteCompoId} />
      <main className="p-4">
        <div>
          {renderContent()}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i use shadcn/ui

this is Bigreact/components/ui/navigation-menu.tsx

```
import * as React from "react"
import * as NavigationMenuPrimitive from "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu"
import { cva } from "class-variance-authority"
import { ChevronDown } from "lucide-react"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"

const NavigationMenu = React.forwardRef<
```

than i npm run dev
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y0Oh.png)

I've been trying to solve this for a few hours, but it's not working, so I would appreciate your help

```
{
  "name": "fairytail",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.1.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.298.0",
    "next": "^14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "swr": "^2.2.4",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

i try package.json

and next.json

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
     
      if (!isServer) {
        config.resolve.alias['@radix-ui/react-slot'] = require.resolve('@radix-ui/react-slot');
        config.resolve.alias['class-variance-authority'] = require.resolve('class-variance-authority');
      }
  
      
      return config;
    },
  };
```

and tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: where do you import global.css?

Comment: I have imported app/globals.css in app/page.tsx. I thought it would be applied 'everywhere' since it was imported in the app directory, but I had to add an import in mainpage.tsx to solve the issue
I'm curious if there is a way to directly import app/globals.css. I copied the file and created pages/globals.css to import it

Comment: oh mainpage is pages/mainpage.tsx

Answer (score 1):

CSS files such as `global.css` needs to be imported in a shared file, in next.js 13 this is `app/layout.tsx`

At the top of `app/layout.tsx` import the main css file:

```js
import "./layout.css"
// ...
export default function RootLayout() {
  // ...
}
```